# UWP Appointments: Appointment ID returning empty

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to add [Appointments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Dn263359) to my UWP App.

I have successfully set up the Appointment but the result for created Appointment Id is empty which means that the appointment is not created.

Following is my Code:

```
        public static Rect GetElementRect(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            GeneralTransform transform = element.TransformToVisual(null);
            Point point = transform.TransformPoint(new Point());
            return new Rect(point, new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
        }
        private async Task<ManagerResponseModel> AddAppointmentToOutlookCalendar(ViewingSummaryModel model)
        {
            ManagerResponseModel result = new ManagerResponseModel();

            //Add appointment if assigned to the same user
            if(model.HousingOfficerId == AppSession.LoggedinUserId)
            {
                // Create an Appointment that should be added the user's appointments provider app.
                var appointment = new Appointment();
                //Populate Viewing Data in appointment
                appointment.Subject = string.Format("Viewing at {0}", model.PropertyAddress);
                appointment.Location = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PropertyAddress)) ? "NA" : model.PropertyAddress;
                appointment.BusyStatus = AppointmentBusyStatus.Tentative;
                appointment.Sensitivity = AppointmentSensitivity.Public;
                appointment.AllDay = false;
                //var timeZoneOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
                var date = GeneralHelper.GetCombinedDateTimeStringForViewing(model.ViewingDate, model.FormattedTime);
                //var startTime = new DateTimeOffset(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, 0, TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset);
                appointment.StartTime = date;
                appointment.Details = string.Format("Customer: {0}", model.CustomerName) + "\r"
                    + string.Format("Housing Officer: {0}", (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.AssignedTo)) ? "NA" : model.AssignedTo) + "\r"
                    + string.Format("Address: {0}", model.PropertyAddress) + "\r"
                    + string.Format("Created by: {0}", (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CreatorName)) ? "You" : model.CreatorName);




                // Get the selection rect of the button pressed to add this appointment
                var rect = GetElementRect(this.Frame as FrameworkElement);
                string appointmentId = string.Empty;
                // ShowAddAppointmentAsync returns an appointment id if the appointment given was added to the user's calendar.
                // This value should be stored in app data and roamed so that the appointment can be replaced or removed in the future.
                // An empty string return value indicates that the user canceled the operation before the appointment was added.

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.OutlookIdentifier))
                {
                    appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowReplaceAppointmentAsync(model.OutlookIdentifier, appointment, rect, Placement.Default, date);
                    /*Appointment doesn't exist on this system, try to add a new one*/
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appointmentId))
                    {
                        appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
                }

                model.OutlookIdentifier = appointmentId;

                result.isSuccessful = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appointmentId);
                result.responseObject = model;
            }
            else
            {
                result.isSuccessful = true;
                result.responseObject = model;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The following line:

```
 appointmentId = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
```

returns empty only if user cancels the operation or there is some other issue resulting in failure in creation of appointment. I am not cancelling the operation, nor is there any raised exception so I have no idea what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after reading a related [thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/cd37cebe-c1bc-4138-8e91-e6b5a8907fb6/creating-an-appointment-in-a-uwp-app-crashes-the-app?forum=wpdevelop). It was a really stupid mistake. I had forgotten to add the Appointments [capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) in my `Package.appxmanifest` file.

So the problem was, my App was not authorized to add appointments to User's calendar which is why the appointment Id was returning empty (Would have been nice if the relevant error was returned too, Microsoft).

To fix this, add the following line to your `package.appxmanifest` file in Capabilities:

```
<Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="appointments" />
</Capabilities>
```

Or alternatively, you can just click on the file, go to Capabilities tab and check the "Appointments" capability like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You should tick this as the answer. ;)

Comment: @JustinXL Can't until tomorrow :3